# React context how it works

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Learning React , and curious to know how the the below way of consuming context works behind the scenes?

```
  static contextType = MyContext;
  render() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* render something based on the value */
  }
}
```

How does `this.context` gets setup automatically by declaring `static contextType` ?

Comment: if you specify a static property on a class say `App`, react can access the property with `App.contextType` and provide the context values as props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that handles this can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.new.js#L531

In short, they check if `ctor.contextType` exists (where `ctor` is the constructor for the component). If it does, they read what the value in context is, and then call the constructor with that value.

```
const contextType = ctor.contextType;
//...
if (typeof contextType === 'object' && contextType !== null) {
    context = readContext((contextType: any));
}
//...
const instance = new ctor(props, context);
```

Comment: And if it's a functional component?

Comment: The link is invalid now.